# O que há de errado na requisição desse script?

Tags: javascript, json, requisição

Em um determinado ponto preciso requisitar um script json ao servidor, porém estou fazendo algumas mudanças e estou obtendo erros que supostamente não deveria acontecer. 
O exemplo abaixo funciona perfeitamente bem:

```
$(".script_episodios").html($("<script />", { 
    src: 'http://dominio.com/js/episodios.php'
}));
/*chamados os dados que foram gerados no script acima*/
console.log(dados_episodios);
```

Já quando faço a mesmo chamada para um outro domínio exclusivo para retornar json, o mesmo já não é processado corretamente

```
$(".script_episodios").html($("<script />", { 
    src: 'http://api.dominio.com/js/episodios.php'
}));
/*chamados os dados chamados no script acima*/
console.log(dados_episodios);
```

No segundo exemplo parece que o script não espera a chamada ser terminada antes de continuar e eu obtenho o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: dados_episodios is not defined`, já consultei o retorno de ambas as requisições é igual, inclusive o tempo médio da requisição é igual para as duas, como posso contornar esse erro?

Comment: Ambos os `src` estão redirecionando para a página: *http://www.domain.com/*. Como pode estar funcionando aí? :O

Comment: Um aponta para o domínio local, outro aponta para o subdominio api

Comment: Mas esse domínio domain.com não leva a um arquivo `json`. Usou apenas como exemplo???

Comment: Com base em parametros passados o PHP pesquisa os dados e manda os mesmos de volta com o json_encode

Answer (score 0):

A técnica de criar script tag com src só funciona para JSONP, se a url retornar JSON ao invés de JSONP você vai ter que fazer uma requisição HTTP normal usando [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ou [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) ou [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Essa requisição pode não funcionar se o servidor não estiver com CORS habilitado, se ele não estiver com cors você pode usar um proxy como o crossorigin.me.

Exemplo usando XMLHttpRequest

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://crossorigin.me/http://api.bluanime.com/dados/animes/113/episodios');
request.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var data = request.response.slice("dados_eps = ".length);
  alert(data);
  var json = JSON.parse(data);
});
request.send();
```

Exemplo usando JSONP alterando a API: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmqgrwdt/

A api retorna algo do tipo

```
callback({"episodes": "123", "_": "1492622616910"});
```

Comment: Mas a página e os parametros passados são os mesmos, só muda que agora a requisição agora é feita para um subdomínio e não para o domínio principal. A mesma é mandada, processada e obtêm um retorno, logo não creio que seja problema com CORS.

Comment: Falta ver se essa outra URL retorna JSON ou JSONP, se retornar só JSON não vai funcionar.

Comment: Aqui um exemplo de retorno para o subdomínio http://api.bluanime.com/dados/animes/113/episodios

Comment: Tenta fazer `setTimeout(() => console.log(dados_eps), 5000);`, as vezes demora um pouco para carregar.

Comment: Mas isso não é aplicável em um site, forçar o carregamento esperar 5 segundos antes de continuar a execução, seria muito inviável

Comment: Só para ver se com isso funciona. Se funcionar você pode colocar essa script tag no html, depois do load a variável vai estar pronta. Outra possibilidade é tentar o ajax.

Comment: Infelizmente não da pra carregar ele junto com o HTML pois é uma página dinâmica, cujo conteúdo é alterado via ajax, logo toda vez que o usuário fizer alguma alteração eu preciso carregar esse script novamente.

Comment: Quer tentar fazer usando ajax? Você vai ter que cortar o começo da string com o var x = {} para pegar só o json.

Comment: Aceito a sugestão desde que não tenha problema com o tempo de resposta

Comment: Tá com o CORS desabilitado então eu tive que usar o proxy crossorigin.me. Seria legal se o pessoal fizesse `fun({...})` ao invés de `var x = {...};` porque evitaria de usar o proxy.

Comment: Eu posso mudar o retorno do json não é problema, como seria se eu só mandasse fun({...})?

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo usando JSONP, ao invés de setar uma variável o código retornado chama uma função previamente definida.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57353/discussion-between-leo-letto-and-waterscroll).